# Not able to extact dictionary from a list in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate over list of dictionaries, but it is giving me `AttributeError`

Here is my code -

```
user_list = []
new_user = { 'last': 'fermi',
             'first': 'enrico',
             'username': 'efermi', }
user_list.append(new_user)


new_user = { 'last': 'fermi2',
             'first': 'enrico2',
             'username': 'efermi2', }
user_list.append(new_user)

for users_dict in user_list:
    for k, v in users_dict.items(): # fails at this line
        if(k == 'username'):
            user_list.append(v)
```

**Exception** -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Derick/PycharmProjects/Puthon3_2019/dictionaries2.py", line
>   14, in 
>       for k, v in users_dict.items(): # fails at this line AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

However if i am accessing dictionary like below is working fine -

```
print(user_list[0].items())
```

I gives me -

```
dict_items([('last', 'fermi'), ('first', 'enrico'), ('username', 'efermi')])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add to a list while iterating over it. `user_list.append(v)` adds a string to the list of dictionaries and it causes the next iteration to fail because it tries to do `.items()` in a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are appending you the same list you are iterating over. On some next iteration, the for loop picks a string instead of a dict from that list, and that's where you get the error.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, you are appending `v`, which is a string, to a list you are iterating as composed by dicts, ending in a mix of strings and dictionaries, which is not advisable. I think it was a sort of typo, fixable by a simple:

```
usernames = []
for users_dict in user_list:
    for k, v in users_dict.items(): # fails at this line
        if(k == 'username'):
            usernames.append(v)
usernames
>>> ['efermi', 'efermi2']
```

or better:

```
usernames = [x["username"] for x in user_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason is you added a `str` to `user_list` in iteration:

```
user_list.append(v)
```

in python, edit while traverse `list` is allowed, and `list` will iterate the new content appended to it.

for example, we can use `list` to do [bfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), traverse and edit at the same time.

```
    for node in bfs:
        bfs += node.successor
    return bfs
```